# CSS relative positioning with negative value and height

Tags: css, height, css-position

I'm trying to negative position a DIV element (in the example is #content), but my problem is the div's container (#wrapper2), gets too much height (actually is the height the #content is giving, but as I'm moving the content up, I would like to decrease the height of #wrapper2 accordingly).

Here I give you an example to show what I'm trying to achieve. If you try the sample, you'll see that footer stays at too many distance from container. I can make a dirty hack here and make footer top:-200px too but then the scroll bar of the window goes over the footer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Relative positioning demo</title>
    <style>
        /* RESET STUFF */
        html {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          border:0;
        }

        body, div, p, h1 {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
        }
        /* END RESET */

        h1 {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        p {
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        /* LAYOUT */
        #wrapper1 {
            text-align: center;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }
        #wrapper2 {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        #content {
            width: 950px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 560px;

            /* HERE's my problem */
            position: relative;
            top: -200px;
        }
        #footer {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }               
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <h1>This is my heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">
        <div id="content">
            My content here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        lorem ipsum
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any suggestions, keep in mind that I must see both, the lightgrey and lightblue background (they're images on my site), so margin-top: -200px is not an option (like someone suggested in related questions that I've searched for)

Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but could you not just set one of the images as the background image in the body, and the other in a positioned div?

Comment: Nice approach boblet, I'm gonna give it a try and see what happens...

Comment: Very good idea boblet. I've not done what you suggested but you've pointed me to the right direction, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references, what I've finally done is to merge the images on the wrapper1 and wrapper 2 in the same image (they were background patterns), so I only have one wrapper now, and I don't need to relative position the content above the second one, it just goes following the page flow.

In the end I've understood that you can't delete the unwanted height without using some sort of Javascript.

Answer (score 14):

Change the `top` property to `margin-top`

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hFftN/1)

```
        position: relative;
        top: -200px;
```

changed to

```
        margin-top: -200px;
```

Comment: Thanks Josep, but as I've stated in the question, this is not an option because the wrapper1 looses all its height (as I've already said it's an image in my real site and if I just set margin-top: -200px as you're suggesting, I'm not going to see it)