# Is it possible to give a css property a negative percentage value?

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage

I have a parent element and I need my child element to be overlapping the parent element. Is it possible to give a negative percentage value? See what I mean below.

```
parent {
   position: absolute;
}
child {
   position: relative;
   top: -20%;
}
```

Currently, when I try to implement the above it understands it only as a positive percentage value (So goes down instead of going up).

Let me know if this is possible or if I should implement a different solution (If so a reference would be much appreciated).

Comment: Yes it's possible. http://jsfiddle.net/h98oLr5L/1/ Interestingly this implementation allows for perfect centering without `margin: auto;`

Comment: all you had to do was this http://jsfiddle.net/323ksyzw/1/ its kind of a strange behavior though (try resizing the Result area)

Comment: it is possible. you need to work around `position`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something clearly listed in the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Paulie_D claimed, my previous answer was not answering the OP question. So this is my new answer:

The correct way to achieve that is using

```
margin-top:-20%;
```

Instead of

```
top:-20%
```

Acording the W3C it is correct to use negative values as margins.
For further info visit this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)

There is also [another question similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893620/css-relative-positioning-with-negative-value-and-height).

Comment: The question wasn't about margins...it was about positioning.

Comment: I agree...but that's not what the OP asked for.